# Why are these two classes executed in python 3.x， They're just defined?

Tags: python-3.x

Why are these two classes executed? I just defined two base classes. I didn't use `f = F ()` and `g = G ()` to instantiate objects. Why are the two prints executed?

```
class F():
    print("F.__new__called")
    
class G:
    print("G.__new__called")

print("test")
```

output:

```
F.__new__called
G.__new__called
test
```

Comment: Unlike function, class body statements are executed when making the class.

Comment: @Henry Tjhia  It belongs to the method of the class? Attributes? Or neither?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about how the interpreter runs through the code. When it sees a class definition(`class` statement), it just creates a new namespace and executes all the statements inside it in the new namespace. That is why your print statements get executed.

When interpreter sees a function definition (`def` statement), it binds the function name in the current namespace to a function object(which represents the code of the function).

```
class ClassName:
  print("hey")
  a = 2

  def f():
     print("test")
```

In the above class, all the statements are executed within the namespace `ClassName`. So `print("hey")` gets executed and the assignment `a = 2` also gets executed. Since `a` is within the namespace `ClassName`, you can refer to it as `ClassName.a`. The statement `def f(self):` also gets executed but since it is a function definition, the name `ClassName.f` binds to the function object which when called (`ClassName.f()`), executes the function code.

Comment: I don't quite understand this sentence ‘also gets executed but since it is a function definition, the name ClassName.f binds to the function object which when called (ClassName.f())’, Can you explain it in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

As in Python 3 docs 9.3.1 ["Class Definition Syntax"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax) (emphasis mine):

> The simplest form of class definition looks like this:
>
> ```
> class ClassName:
>   <statement-1>
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   <statement-N>
> ```
>
> **Class definitions, like function definitions (def statements) must be executed before they have any effect.** (You could conceivably place a class definition in a branch of an if statement, or inside a function.)
>
> In practice, the statements inside a class definition will usually be function definitions, but **other statements are allowed, and sometimes useful** — we’ll come back to this later. The function definitions inside a class normally have a peculiar form of argument list, dictated by the calling conventions for methods — again, this is explained later.

As far as Python is concerned, any statement is allowed within a `class` definition, even beyond typical attribute assignment and function definitions. These statements are run immediately, in the same sense that the `def` statement must be run to define a function.

(The docs do not obviously come back to the utility of other statements in the block, though other examples interleave assignments for private variable references in the 9.6 code block.)

However, unlike the contents of your print statement, these do *not* correspond to "F.__new__called"; it only corresponds to the class being defined. When you call `f = F ()`, Python will call the *methods* `__new__` and `__init__`, which then are responsible for constructing the object.